# What is wall in golang Time?

Tags: go, time

I was testing a feature where I had to write a record with `created_at` field which is of type `time.Time` into a Mysql table. When I read the same record back I get following diff.

```
                                    Time: (time.Time) {
                                -    wall: (uint64) 454722000,
                                +    wall: (uint64) 0,
```

What is `wall` in golang `Time` and why are they different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Monotonic Clocks section](https://pkg.go.dev/time#hdr-Monotonic_Clocks) of the [time package documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/time) describes monatomic and wall clock time in detail. The section covers the scenario of reading a time from a database.

See [Equal](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Equal) for information on how to compare time values.

Answer (score 1):

The real reason for me has to do with `nano seconds`. Apparently when I write to db `nano seconds` are stripped off. So what I did is created a function that would return me current time but without `nano seconds`.